# Saving multiple instance at once

Tags: django

Following code saving only one instance in database. I've added `range` so it should be 3. Is something wrong? Thanks

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    for coupon in range(3):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.name = 'test'
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```

Comment: What is formset? can u enlighten us with some more of the code?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh I am using `Inline formsets`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever formset may be, each of the three times, you are taking the same elements from that formset and are saving it. So the same change is overwritten everytime, so it looks like the change is made only once.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same issue using `instance.pk = None` before `instance.save()`. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but it worked!